# Conditionally adding an extra LI to a list in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple React component that iterates over a list of items, and each item includes it as a Component. The trick is every 3rd list item, I want to inject a "special" extra li.

So, my "pseudo react code" looks something like this:

```
return (<ul>
  {
     data.myItems.items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
           <li><MyItem key={index} {...item} /></li>
           { (index % 3 === 0) &&
              <li>Special LI</li>      
           }
        );
     })
  }
</ul>);
```

This obviously doesn't work since my `return(..)` potentially returns 2 top-level elements (2 li's).

I can't wrap the 2 divs in something else it will break the semantics of ul/li (i need them all to be siblings in a list of depth 1).

I figure there has to be a simple way to do this that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a fragment element. More on fragments [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

```
return (<ul>
  {
     data.myItems.items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
        <>
        <li><MyItem key={index} {...item} /></li>
           { (index % 3 === 0) &&
              <li>Special LI</li>      
           }
        </>
        );
     })
  }
</ul>);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap it in an empty tag. In react, it is called **Fragment**.

```
return (<ul>
  {
     data.myItems.items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
           <>
             <li><MyItem key={index} {...item} /></li>
              { (index % 3 === 0) &&
                <li>Special LI</li>      
              }
           </>
        );
     })
  }
</ul>);
```